# How do you unlock Classified Weapons?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops-3

I was wondering how to get the Classified Weapons added in the Febuary Update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of the classified items in Black Ops III (including the **classified weapons**) are obtained through the Black Market in Multiplayer as a random drop. There is a higher chance to get them if you use the 30-Cryptokey / 200 CoD Point chest (that guarantees at least ONE item of a high rarity, which includes the classified weapons), but it is ultimately up to chance.

Comment: To the person that claimed you could specifically buy the weapons themselves with CoD Points: no, you can't, and that is one of the biggest complaints leveled at Activision over this - you have to rely on what is essentially a reskinned Supply Drop mechanic to get them.

Comment: After you get the item in the chest, do you still need to do something to unlock it? Be a certain level or use an unlock token, for example.

Comment: Classified weapons do NOT appear to be level-locked, nor do they require unlock tokens after being obtained from the random drop. (this does mean that someone could get stupidly lucky and get a melee weapon in their first black market crate, giving them an equivalent to the knife without the level requirement)